# write in bashrc file with jenkins

Tags: bash

I want to write a variable in bashrc file with help of jenkins if the variable doesn't exist. I write this in execute shell

```
if [[ ! -d "$var" ]]; then 
    export var="ip"
    echo 'export var="ip"' >> ~/.bashrc;
fi
```

This writes in bashrc file but the issue is that it writes everytime jenkins job is build.I just want to write in once. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(I am not on any server so couldn't check it but this should be the logic).

```
if [[ ! -d "$var" ]]; then 
    export var="ip"
    if [[ -z  $(grep  'export var ="ip"' ~/.bashrc) ]]
    then
         echo 'export var="ip"' >> ~/.bashrc;
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Hi,your script is almost perfect but just remove the space b/w var and = and change it to if [[ -z  $(grep  'export var="ip"' ~/.bashrc) ]]

Comment: @AnshulWalia, you actually don't need space between `var` and `=` it shouldn't be the case, lemme know in case you have any more queries here?